# How to cast an integer to np.object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, type-conversion

Yes, I am fully aware that `isinstance(-1, np.object)` returns `True`.

However, `-1 != "-1"` (obviously) and there lies my problem.

I read a `DataFrame` from a CSV file where `-1` is used to denote missing data:

```
Numbers,Strings
1,A
2,-1
-1,B
```

and [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) produces:

```
   Numbers Strings
0        1       A
1        2      -1
2       -1       B
```

with `dtypes`

```
Numbers     int64
Strings    object
dtype: object
```

I have a `missing_value` variable which is `-1` and

```
>>> missing_value = -1
>>> for c in z.columns:
      print(c,(z[c] == missing_value).sum())
Numbers 1
Strings 0
>>> (z.Strings == str(missing_value)).sum()
1
```

I understand *why* this is happening.
My question is how to modify the loop so it will DTRT:

```
for c in z.columns:
   print(c,(z[c] == (missing_value if np.issubdtype(z[c].dtype,np.number) else str(missing_value))).sum())
Numbers 1
Strings 1
```

Is this really the right way?

PS. Extra constraints:

1. I have no control over the CSV file format.
2. The CSV is huge, I would rather operate on `missing_value` than on the whole table.
3. Some fields are missing (as in being `""`), and this is semantically different from being `-1`, so passing `na_values=-1` to `read_csv` is not an option.
4. In fact I am not just counting the missing values, I pass `df[c]` and `missing_value` to a function `do_complicated_analysis_on_a_series`.

Comment: Why not tell pandas to treat -1 as NaN from the start? `pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv',na_values=-1)`

Comment: @DYZ: because some fields are genuinely missing (and thus read as `na`)

Comment: @sds: Why would that stop you from using `na_values`?

Comment: @user2357112: because I don't want `""` to be treated identically to `-1`.

Comment: Ok, another option is to convert the dataframe to strings and compare it to "-1". `(z.astype('str')=="-1").sum()`

Comment: @DYZ: I don't want to convert the DF (see PS); especially not the numeric columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about separating the object and numeric columns and treating them differently?

```
part1 = (z.loc[:, z.dtypes != np.object] == -1).sum()
#Numbers    1
#dtype: int64
part2 = (z.loc[:, z.dtypes == np.object] == str(-1)).sum()
#Strings    1
#dtype: int64
```

The results can be concatenated into one dataframe, if necessary.

```
np.concat([part1, part2])
```

Comment: But you don't have to. My solution does not have explicit loops.

Comment: I _DO_ need a loop - I am doing *MUCH* more than just counting the missing values.

Comment: Your question is very unclear at this point. I suggest you rewrite it.

Comment: Please see PS4 ;-(

Comment: There are not too many cases when you really need to loop through the columns in pandas. Perhaps you are overcomplicating your problem.

Answer (score 1):

We can fix your output by `isin`

```
df.isin([-1,'-1']).sum()

Out[276]: 
Numbers    1
Strings    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I need to operate on a "per-column" basis. Also, my DF is huge, so I would rather operate on `missing_value` than on `df`.

Comment: `object` columns may contain both `-1` and `"-1"` - not in my specific case though - so I really don't like the `isin` approach.